# Given Two Circles Intersect Each Other. Find the Area. Does This Question Have an Error?

Tags: trigonometry, circles

> > 2 circle instersect each other. One with radius 1, another with radius r. Form $120^\circ$,  outside the two cricles. 
> >     [image]

1. AB = $\sqrt{r^2 - r + 1}$ (matched key answer)
2. I find r = 0.5 (matched key answer)

So. AB = $\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}$

3. However. I have been thinking hours about 3rd problems..
   I think this is what the plane looks like more or less :
   [image]

But. I found that with
 APB = $120^\circ$,
AB is not  $\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}$
Is there error with the question? Or where am i wrong?

Is there more effective way to solve it?

Comment: why did you make tangents go through circle centers?

Comment: notice that in your drawing the angle formed by the tangent lines is actually $90°$. Do you see why?

Comment: Because the line go through circle centers?

Comment: Why it is 90 degrees? APQ goes through circle center too

Comment: $PB$ is a radius and thus perpendicular to the tangent $AP$, and vice versa.

Comment: Ok. I meant APQ in your drawing. Ok i get it. Also. Why do you know the center of Cr inside intersection?

Comment: 'cause $AB < AP$?

Comment: Oh. True.. thank you

Comment: Why you think it is exactly half of Cr is the intersection?

Comment: you mean why the line connecting intersection points $P$ and $Q$ passes though center of $\mathcal C_r$?

Comment: Yes. Why is that?

Comment: added some details in my answer, below the figure.

Comment: I added further details on the general case in my answer. Let me know is this clarifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation, with $r = \frac12$, is shown in the picture below. From the fact that $\overline{AB} = \frac{\sqrt 3} 2$, $\overline{PB} = \frac12$, and $\overline{AP} = 1$, we gather that $\triangle APQ$ is equilateral.

You can then determine the area of the intersection between the two circles by summing half of the area of circle $\mathcal C_r$ with a circular segment of circle $\mathcal C$ subtended by an angle of $60°$ (that is, one sixth of the circle area minus the area of the equilateral triangle). This gives
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal A&=& \frac{\pi}{8}+\left(\frac{\pi}{6}-\frac{\sqrt 3}{4}\right)=\\
&=& \frac{7\pi}{24} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}.
\end{eqnarray}

[image]

**EDIT**
To better understand the situation, you can proceed as follows.

Draw circle $\mathcal C$, with center in $A$ then draw a diameter and take $B$ on it such that $\overline{AB} = \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$. $B$ is going to be the center of $\mathcal C_r$.

Now draw the line through $B$ perpendicular to $AB$, that intersects $\mathcal C$ in $P$ and $Q$. From Pythagorean Theorem, $\overline{PB} = \frac{1}{2}$, so $\mathcal C_r$ is the circle with center in $B$ and passing through $P$ and $Q$.

**EDIT 2** The general case is shown in the figure below.

By construction we have that $\angle TPS = 120°$. From the fact that radii are perpendicular to tangent lines we have $\angle APS = 90°$ and $\angle TPB = 90°$.

Therefore we have $\angle TPA = 30°$ and $\angle APB = 60°$.

Draw from $A$ the line perpendicular to $PB$, and call $H$ its intersection with $PB$. Since $\triangle APH$ is half of an equilateral triangle, $\overline{PH} = \frac12\cdot \overline{AP} = \frac12$, and, by Pythagorean Theorem, $\overline{AH} = \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$. $\overline{PB} = r$ by definition. Thus $\overline{HB} =r-\frac12$.

Again Pythagorean Theorem, on $\triangle AHB$, gives, in conclusion
\begin{eqnarray}
\overline{AB}^2 &=& \frac34 + \left(r-\frac12\right)^2=\tag{1}\label{eq1}\\
&=& r^2-r+1.
\end{eqnarray}

From \eqref{eq1},
$$\overline{AB}^2 \geq \frac34,$$
with the minimum attained when $r=\frac12$ and thus $H\equiv B$, as in the figure above.

[image]

Comment: APB. Is that matched phytagoras? 1, 0.25, $\sqrt3$/2

Comment: @Lifeforbetter correct

Comment: No. It doesn't...?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter the smaller side is $1/2$

Comment: Ok. True. Thank you

Comment: How to find AB with your drawing? It is not matched key answer..?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter $AB$ is $\sqrt 3/2$ **by construction**.

Comment: Sorry. What i meant is answer question 1 based on your drawing. Find AB in terms of r

Comment: @Lifeforbetter, well, of course you **cannot** use the drawing to demonstrate point 1., since the drawing is based on the specific case found in point 2.

I thought you did not need a demonstration of 1. and 2. since you already found the correct answers yourself. Was I wrong?

Comment: Yes. I found the answer for 1 and 2 based on my drawing... but i cannot find it with yours. From my drawing. $AB^2 = AP^2 + BP^2 - 2AP. BP.Cos120$

Comment: @Lifeforbetter you cannot because my drawing has $r$ fixed and equal to $\frac12$. Your drawing shows a different instance of the situation, where $r \neq \frac{1}{2}$ and thus $\overline{AB} \neq \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$, but that is fine if you just need to find the *relationship* between $\overline{AB}$ and $r$.

Comment: Oh. Right.. ok. Thank you

Comment: @Lifeforbetter, well, to be precise, your drawing **does not** show a correct instance, since, as we said, the angle between tangents, there, isn't $120°$.

Comment: Oh.. right.. i will try

Comment: Yes. Thank you for the help

Comment: △APH is half equilateral from △APB?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter $APB$ is equilateral only in the special case of the first figure, though.

Comment: You said in 2nd figure : 
Draw from $A$ the line perpendicular to $PB$, and call $H$ its intersection with $PB$. Since $\triangle APH$ is half of an equilateral triangle,  But. I don't think $\triangle APH$ is half of an equilateral triangle, in 2nd figure.

Comment: @Lifeforbetter yes it is, it's a right-angled triangle with 90-60-30 degrees angles. That's what I meant.

Comment: So, you get $\overline{PH} = 1/2 \overline{AP}$ because of $\sin 30^{\circ}$?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter no need for trigonometry in this case: take any equilateral triangle and draw an altitude. What you get are to right-angled triangles similar to $APH$.

Comment: How to know PH = 1/2 AP?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter read again my comment above and consider that in an equilateral triangle, altitudes and medians coincide!

Comment: APH is right triangle, but APB not a equlateral....?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter no, it's not. I'm talking about properties of of **any** 90-60-30 right-angle triangles... No need to consider $\triangle APB$, at this aim...

Comment: So, it is always another side is half hypotenuse side? In right angle triangles..

Comment: @Lifeforbetter if the angles are 90-60-30, of course yes.

Comment: Ok, thank you...

Comment: BTW, what program you use to draw this plane?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter Geogebra